# Get the maxWidth of a UIFont

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont

I need to get the maxWidth (in points) of a arbitrary character for a particular font.

Basically, I have an array of strings that all have four characters. I need to compute what the max width that one of these strings could possibly be. UIFont has a bunch of methods for calculating the height in different circumstances, but nothing to compute width.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The methods needed to calculate the width are in NSString UIKit Additions:

```
– sizeWithFont:
– sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
– sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
```

Comment: I don't think those will work for what I need. Those are computing the widths for actual strings. I need to compute the width based only on the number of characters. Basically, I need the width of the widest character for a given UIFont.

Comment: Find the widest character (with a loop for every char) for your font and multiply by the number of characters.